# How to pass parameters to Html.BeginForm(action, controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input name= "number1" /><br />
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Contoller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetNumber(int number1)
{
}
```

works fine whereas the following code

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction","SomeContoller"))
{
    <input name= "number1" /><br />
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(int number1)
{
}
```

is not working. I tried without the parameter its working then, but i am not able to get the value for number1 to this contoller. How would I do that?.

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I don't think the tag "asp-classic" is correct for this question, please review.

Answer (score 4):

Do you use for controller name parameter something like "HomeController" or just "Home"? Because i think that only the prefix should be there.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Home"))
{
    <input name= "number1" /><br />
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<input id="number1" />` ?

Comment: No, it must be 'name' parameter. (it is enough if it is just 'name')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction","SomeControler",new {number1 = 1}, FormMethod.Post))
    {                 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```